# Input type checkbox is not working in my project

Tags: reactjs, input, checkbox, dependencies

I tried to create an input type checkbox in my react project which was already finished, I just wanted to try some new things in it. But the checkbox is not shown. I ran a new empty project and I copy paste the code off the input and it worked perfectly. I don't know where to start looking. Could it have something to do with the dependencies or something like that? Is not a route or a library problem because I used the most basic code.
This is the code I wrote in my new project which works perfectly:

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div >
    Select your pizza topping:
    <div className="topping">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topping" name="topping" value="Paneer" />Paneer
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is code from the original project, everything works except the input:

```
import * as React from 'react';

const Contact = () => {
   

        return (
         
    <div className="exemplo">
        Select your pizza topping:
     <div className="topping">
       <input type="checkbox" id="topping" name="topping" value="Paneer" />
    </div>
  </div>
          );


}

export default Contact
```

It has no sense because is the same code, so I have absolutely no idea what the problem is, if someone could tell me where to start looking that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Hi @Sofia.
It would be really helpful if you share more of your code.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @MhkAsif thanks, already edited it!

Comment: The code seems fine to me. Can you do a favor of putting this in codesandbox? It'll be easier to debug. Thanks